# Many to many - save/update in joining table and one table only

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have many to many relationship between Person and Group tables and the joining table is PersonGroup. When I save/delete Person, it saves and deletes from `Person, PersonGroup and Group` tables.

I only want to delete/save from "Person" and "PersonGroup" tables and leave `Group table untouched.` 
And on query for "Person", I should get "Group" list in the Person entity.

So basically "Group" is a reference table. It should only be read from, no delete/update on Group table.

How can I achieve this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id     
    private long personId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="PersonGroup", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="person_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="group_id"))
    private List<Group> groups;

    }


@Entity
@Table(name="Group")
public class Group implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private long groupId;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="groups")
    private List<Person> persons;

}
```

Comment: I have the same problem to solve.  I only need join table updated.  What did you come up with.  Yes, 6 years old, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Cascading means that if you insert, update or delete an object, related objects are inserted, updated or deleted as well.

If you want to leave `Group` table untouched when you save/delete/update an `Person` just remove the `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` property from the `@ManyToMany` annotation.

try the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id     
    private long personId;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Group.class, mappedBy="persons")
    private List<Group> groups;

}


@Entity
@Table(name="Group")
public class Group implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private long groupId;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Person.class)
    @JoinTable(name="PersonGroup",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="person_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="group_id"))
    private List<Person> persons;

}
```

Comment: Removeing the cascadetyp.all does not save it in Group table but it also doesn't save it in the joining table `PersonGroup`

Comment: The javadoc of mappedBy is a bit misleading...

You should map your join table on the side that does not "own" the relationship and use mappedBy on the side that does "own" the relationship...

the way it is now, i think hibernate would update the jointable if you saved the Group object...

i will edit my answer to address that